# Give timestamp in milliseconds how do I find out if it is older than 2 days

Tags: java, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a timestamp which I get from

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

**Questions**

1. How do I find out if this is older than 2 days in my code .?
2. Is there a better way to assigning timestamp during creation instead of using system.currentTimeMillis ?
3. Is  System.currentTimeMillis() machine agnostic and does it give UTC time ?
   Thank you !

Comment: What does "2 days" mean to you? Exactly 48 hours? Two calendar days, and if so by which time zone do we perceive the date?

Comment: I want to check if the timestamp is older than 2 days/48 hours . So that I can expire the object

Comment: 2 days is not necessarily 48 hours. Two days might be 47, 47.5, 49, or some other number of hours.

Comment: What does “machine agnostic” mean to you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Instant                              // Represents a moment as seen in UTC.
    .ofEpochMilli( yourCount )       // Convert a count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z to an `Instant` object.
    .isBefore(                       // Compares one `Instant` object to another.
        Instant                      
        .now()                       // Capture the current moment as seen in UTC (an offset of zero).
        .minus(                      // Instantiate another `Instant` object for another moment, per immutable objects pattern.
            Duration.ofHours( 48 )   // Define a span-of-time, not attached to the timeline, on a scale of hours-minutes-seconds.
        )                            // Returns another `Instant` object.
    )                                // Returns `boolean` primitive.
```

## Question 1

> How do I find out if this is older than 2 days in my code .?

Parse your [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) `long` integer number as a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_628_125_542_977L ) ;
```

You want to go back 48 hours apparently.

```
Duration fortyEightHours = Duration.ofHours( 48 ) ;
Instant ago48Hours = Instant.now().minus( fortyEightHours ) ;
```

Compare.

```
boolean momentIsMoreThan48HoursAgo = instant.isBefore( ago48Hours ) ;
```

## Question 2

> Is there a better way to assigning timestamp during creation instead of using system.currentTimeMillis ?

Yes, the better way is `Instant`.

Instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()` I suggest you just work with `Instant` class. Depending on the Java implementation, you can expect to capture the current moment with a resolution of either milliseconds on microseconds.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
String outputIso8601 = now.toString() ;
long millisSinceEpoch = now.toEpochMilli() ;
```

Unless you have an extreme need for compact data, I suggest you serialize date-time values using strings in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format rather than as mysterious numbers.

For the current moment, the format would be: `2021-08-04T23:06:06Z` where `T` separates the year-month-day from the time-of-day, and the `Z` means `+00:00` an offset-from-UTC of zero.

## Question 3

> Is not is `System.currentTimeMillis()` machine agnostic and does it give UTC time ?

I do not know what you mean by "machine agnostic". That call does track time, and it does depend on the hardware clock of your host computer being set correctly.

As for UTC time, yes the method `System.currentTimeMillis()` is documented as returning the number of [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) (give or take, depending on resolution of host computer’s hardware clock) since the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) of first moment of 1970 as seen with an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero hours-minutes-seconds, 1970-01-01T00:00Z, while ignoring [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).

The `Instant` class does the same, but can represent a moment with the finer granularity of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) rather than milliseconds. For capturing the current moment, conventional computer hardware clocks are currently accurate only to range of milliseconds to [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond), not nanoseconds.

---

All of this has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. [Search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20instant&t=osx&ia=web) to learn more.

Comment: thank you , what would be the difference between System.currentTimeMillis() and Instant.now() , does this also give UTC time ? 
If so is it also machine agnostic ?

Comment: (a) Regarding to the first question of your comment, see my edits. (b) Please define "machine agnostic".

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.

```
long millisecond = System.currentTimeMillis();
Instant fixedTime =
        Instant.ofEpochMilli(millisecond);
```

Here you can see the duration of elapsed time change every 5 seconds

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ie){}
    Duration duration = Duration.of(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    -millisecond, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
    System.out.println(duration);
}
```

You could also get the elapsed duration by subtracting the current milliseconds from the previous and then comparing. I chose `hours` but you can use any unit representative of two days.

```
Duration duration = Duration.of(System.currentTimeMillis()
             -millisecond, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);

if (duration.toHours() >= 48) {
    System.out.println("Two days have elapsed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### ZonedDateTime

Don’t just use the `long` value from `System.currentTimeMillis()` as your timestamp. Use a proper date-time object from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Also, while `System.currentTimeMillis()` would be machine agnostic — well, dependent on the machine clock, but assuming that that clock has been set correctly, `System.currentTimeMillis()` is machine and time zone agnostic. But *2 days* is not. Because of summer time (DST) and other time anomalies a day may be 23, 24 or 25 hours or some other duration in your time zone.

To handle all of the above, choose a time zone in which you want to count the 2 days. The choice of time zone matters. Then use `ZonedDateTime`. It knows its time zone and handles summer time transitions, etc., correctly. To obtain your timestamp:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/St_Lucia");
    ZonedDateTime timestamp = ZonedDateTime.now(zone);
```

To check whether it is older than 2 days:

```
    ZonedDateTime twoDaysAgo = ZonedDateTime.now(zone).minusDays(2);
    if (timestamp.isBefore(twoDaysAgo)) {
        System.out.println("Timestamp is older than 2 days");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Timestamp is *not* older than 2 days");
    }
```

Since in this case the timestamp is of course fresh, the output I got when I ran the code right now, was:

> ```
> Timestamp is *not* older than 2 days
> ```